# React display loading animation for api call duration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Currently I feel like the more I read about React, the less I understand.

I am trying to solve this simple problem: During the data-fetching for my component, show a loading spinner.

This is how I thought it would work:

1. use State to monitor loading
   `const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);`
2. use conditional rendering on this state
   `return ({isLoading && <div>I am loading</div>});`
3. setLoading when api call is started and reset it when a reponse arrived

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      let result;
      setIsLoading(true);    
      result = await api.get(URL);    // this takes 2000ms!
      setData(result.data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData();
   },[api]);
   ```

But, as the documentation says, `setState` is async and can be sent in batches. the network call takes 2 seconds, but I never see a loading animation.
So how do I do this?

Edit: This is how you can do this. My error was somewhere else - the `setIsLoading(false)` was also in a different `useEffect`, which had the data as dependency. I had to wrap the entire logic inside that `useEffect` with `if(data)`, since on the first render, my data was undefined, but this still triggered the initial `useEffect`, probably like the old componentDidMount logic I guess - and the loading anim stopped way too soon.

Comment: I think what you've got there works. I've implemented it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-leftpad-7uw3w?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Could you give us some more code, or tell us why you have api as a dependency? For your particular case, the brackets can be empty.

Comment: Huh, you are right. Thanks. I have another useEffect with [data] as dependancy, no reason why that one is being activated so early. Never thought the error occurs because of that one.

Comment: No problem :) Have a look at the useEffect docs, it simulates some events you might be interested in.

Comment: :) I was replying to @TKoL, the [api] is there for readability / guarantee that api has been intiliazed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you've got there works. I've implemented it here: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-leftpad-7uw3w?file=/src/App.js)

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      let result;
      setIsLoading(true);
      result = await api.get(URL); // this takes 2000ms!
      //setData(result.data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {isLoading ? <p>currently loading</p> : null}
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const api = {
  get: async function () {
    await new Promise((r, e) => setTimeout(r, 2000));
  }
};
```